# Is it possible to have a girl reincarnate of Asura and Indra?

Tags: naruto

Though I haven't seen an instance where the reincarnate of Asura and Indra is a girl, I'm still wondering. So the question is, is it possible to have a girl reincarnate of Asura and Indra?

Comment: Good question. That also raises the point of what happens if the reincarnates have offspring, assuming that girl reincarnations are allowed. Do the offspring have Rinnegan? Do they naturally have both Senju and Uchiha abilities?

Comment: They only reincarnated twice

Comment: 2 reincarnations is what we know. Considering the time-span between the two reincarnations and the time-span between Naruro & Rikudo, there should be more than 2 reincarnations.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Zetsu implied that he had contacted multiple generations of reincarnates, all ending in failure. The two generations that we are familiar with are only the most recent.

Comment: I agree with TheBlueFish

Comment: @JefferyTang I would bet they would not have the Rinnegan. Ashuras and Indras Chakra does not seem to pass on to their children, but instead just reincarnate later into the next able body once they both die. Tsudnade is Hashiramas Granddaughter, but does not have any of Asuras chakra as we know. Though they may choose to change that in the Boruto manga for the new Kids, And if Boruto and Sarada hook up...

Comment: Yes, BoruSara here we go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any mention of any other incarnates in the manga. It's entirely possible since it's simply chakra reincarnating to a different body, however it's unprovable.

Purely Theoretically: It does seem as though, from what we've seen and what we know of Asura and Indra, that all of his reincarnations would be descendants of them. Indra and his two known reincarnations (Madara and Sasuke) all have been Uchiha (descendants of Indra) and have had the Sharingan. Asura and his two known reincarnations (Hashirama and Naruto) are Senju and Uzumaki, descendants of Asura's clan. This may be because their decedents share similar chakra (Uchiha have the Sharingan, and Uzumaki/Senju have incredible chakra control and chakra reserves). Theoretically, as long as they're a member of one of these clans they can be a reincarnation.

Comment: I also agree with you also according to wiki : Reincarnation is a process through which the chakra and soul of a deceased individual are reborn in a new living vessel ... So the requirement here is one new living vessel and girl is one living vessel too.

Comment: I'd also wager that gender does not play a role in this cycle. While there is very little explanation for *why* the reincarnations continue (aside from bad feelings), it is ultimately a transference of soul. Given how well someone such as Orochimaru is able to manipulate these things, I'd imagine some supernatural means wouldn't care either.

Comment: Naruto was Uzumaki as well kamikaze. Since he did not have red hair , does it not tell he lacked Uzumaki powers. As in nagatos death his hair turned white when he had lost his chakara

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Naruto was Namikaze, not kamikaze (though he used kamikaze tactics a lot =P). Just because he didn't get his mother's red hair doesn't mean he lacked the trademark Uzumaki chakra reserves -- indeed, it was stated that even without Kurama he had a lot of chakra (http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki , under "Chakra and Physical Prowess")